# Quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ of polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in the field of rational numbers. Consider the quotient field $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ and let $K$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ given by $K:=\mathbb{Q}(X)[d]$.

Let $O_{K}$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb Q[X]$ in $K$. Certainly $O_{K}$ contains both $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $d$, hence
$$ O_{K}\supseteq \mathbb{Q}[X][d].$$
Do you think the previous inclusion is strict, or the equality holds?

**EDIT.** The conclusion $O_{K}\supseteq \mathbb{Q}[X][d]$ is false. So the question is: who is $O_{K}$?

Comment: What is $d$? ${}$

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan the root of a monic irreducible polynomial of degree 2 with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(X)$

Comment: For example, we could take $\,d\,$ to be such that $\,d^2=X\iff d\,$ is a root of $\,p(t):=t^2-X\in\Bbb Q[x][t]\,$...?

Comment: @DonAntonio i've already considered that case in another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329284/integral-closure-of-mathbbqx-in-mathbbqxy?noredirect=1#comment711757_329284

Comment: @DonAntonio now i'm considering a generic quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(X)$

Comment: Capisco, @FedericaMaggioni ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write:    "Certainly $O_{K}$ contains both $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $d$, hence
$ O_{K}\supseteq \mathbb{Q}[X][d]$"

But this is not true:
Take $d=\sqrt \frac {1}{X}$, a root ot $T^2-\frac {1}{X}\in \mathbb Q(X)[T]$.
Then $d$ is not integral over $\mathbb Q[X]$ because if it were, then also $d^2=\frac {1}{X}$, would be integral over $\mathbb Q[X]$ and we both know very well that this is absurd.
So, $d\notin O_K$ and thus   $ O_{K}\supseteq \mathbb{Q}[X][d]$ does not hold.

**Edit**
As for the computation of $O_K$, here is a result which may be of help: it is given as Theorem 9.2 (page 65) in Matsumura's *Commutative ring theory*.

> **Theorem**
>    Let $A$ be an integrally closed domain and $K$ an algebraic extension of its field of fraction  $F=Frac(A)$.
>    Then an element $k\in K$ is integral over $A$ iff its minimal polynomial over $F$, the monic polynomial $f(T)=Irr(k,F,T)\in F[T]$,   has its coefficients in $A$.

In your case, if  you suppose for example that $d=\sqrt {P(X)}$ with $P(X)\in \mathbb Q|X]$ a square-free polynomial, the theorem above will allow you to prove that $O_K$ is the ring $\mathbb Q[X][d]$ (details in Matsumura).
(The above class of examples generalizes the result of your [preceding question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329284/integral-closure-of-mathbbqx-in-mathbbqxy?noredirect=1#comment711757_329284) but doesn't completely solve the  problem of calculating $O_K$ for general quadratic extensions $K$  of $\mathbb Q(X)$).

Comment: whoops, you are completely right, so how can i compute $O_{K}$ in this case?

Comment: Dear Federica, first let me congratulate you on your comment: everybody makes mistakes but it takes laudable maturity to quickly recognize one's error. I'll write a little edit addressing the  computation of $O_K$.

Comment: I think the most important question here is not the computation of $O_K$ which can turns out to be cumbersome. It would be very nice to know when $O_K=R[d]$, where $R=\mathbb Q[X]$ (or, in general, an integral domain.) The answer is known for $R$ a Dedekind domain and says the following: $O_K=R[d]$ iff the minimal polynomial of $d$ over $K$ (the field of fractions of $R$) doesn't belong to $M^2$ for all maximal ideals $M$ of $R[X]$.