# Let $D$ be a UFD. If an element of $D$ is not a square in $D$ then is it true that it is not a square in the fraction field of $D$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $D$ be a UFD, let $F$ be the field of fractions of $D$, let $a \in D$ be such that $x^2 \ne a, \forall x \in D$. Then is it true that $x^2\ne a ,\forall x \in F$ ?

(This problem is motivated from the fact that if square root of an integer is not an integer, then the square root is not rational. I know that in the problem, if we drop the UFD condition on $D$ then it is not valid, for example $D=\{f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x] : x^2 | f(x)-f(0)  \}$ and $a=x^2$.)

Comment: It's a little overkill, and I think is basically the same as Bill Dubuque's answer, but: $D$ is integrally closed and any such $x \in F$ is integral over $D$.

Comment: @Hoot Right, but if the OP knew about integral closure then they probably would also know the basic fact that UFDs (or GCD domains) are integrally closed (i.e. the monic case of the Rational Root Test).

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, completely agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it follows from Gauss Lemma. $x^2-a$ is irreducible in $D$ and therefore it must be irreducible in $F$. In particular, it can't have any root.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true. To see this, let $p$  an irreducible element in $D$. Consider the valuation $v_p$ on $F$. If we have $x=y^2$ in $F$, then
 $$v_p(x)=2v_p(y),$$
so every irreducible factor appears with an even exponent. As units can be incorporated into irreducible elements, this proves that, if $x$ is a square in $F$, it is a square in $D$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this, and I'm sure it's just me being silly: if I have $x = up^2$ ($u$ a unit, $p$ a prime) then how do I "incorporate" $u$ in into $p$? I feel like you need to get more information out of $x = y^2$ than just the fact that the prime powers in $x$ are even.

Answer (score 1):

The [standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) of the Rational Root Test works in any UFD, so any root of $\,x^2-a\,$ in the fraction field of $D$ must be in $D,\,$ exactly as in the classical case $\,D = \Bbb Z$.