# Proving normality of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> One of the exercises in Ravi Vakil's algebraic geometry notes, Ex. $5.4.$I(b), is to show that 
>   $$
> \operatorname{Spec}\left(k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_m^2)\right)
> $$
>   is normal, where $k$ is any field of $\operatorname{char}(k)\neq 2$, and $n \geq m \geq 3$.

I have absolutely no idea how to get started on this. Is there anyone that could give a hint as to how one would approach this problem?

Comment: One way to show this is using the Jacobian criterion. If I remember correctly, then there is another way to see that using non-degeneracy of a matrix associated to $\sum x_i^2$.

Comment: This is also an exercise in Hartshorne, Chapter II, Section 6. He gives some hints there.

Comment: As Fredrik mentioned, use induction on $m$ and exercise 6.4 of chapter II in Hartshorne.

Comment: @Youngsu: The jacobian criterion only works outside of the singularity $(0,\dotsc,0)$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I'm a bit confused by your comment. Can you explain?

Comment: And I'm confused by your comment ;). What do you mean exactly by "using the Jacobian criterion"?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Hi. Let me be more specific. I thought the Jacobian ideal is $(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ which has codimension at least $2$. Isn't this enough to conclude that the ring is normal? I was confused by the part "only works outside the origin." Let me know if my question makes sense to you this time.

Answer (score 6):

The following steps lead to a solution:

> > **Step 1:** Suppose the characteristic of a field $k$ is not $2$. If $f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is square-free and non-constant, then $A = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n][z]/(z^2 - f)$ is integrally closed.

Hint for step 1: Follow the method that I employ in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329284/integral-closure-of-mathbbqx-in-mathbbqxy/329301#329301).

> > **Step 2:** Show that the ring in your question above is a domain and then show it is integrally closed using step 1. **Hint for showing that it is a domain:** Dehomogenize with respect to the last variable and apply Eisenstein's Criterion.
> >
> > **Step 3:** Conclude your result.

Comment: In fact, isn't this the exercise (in Vakil) before the OP's question?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Indeed it is. I hadn't looked in Vakil before posting this, I was just posting how I did an identical exercise in Hartshorne chapter II, section 6 (Divisors).

Comment: @Benja, I thought Eisenstein's criterion only applied to polynomials in one variable. How do you want to apply it to $x_1^2+...+x_{m-1}^2+1$ to show that it is irreducible?

Comment: @Rodrigo Apply it to the ring in the variable $x_{m-1}$ with coefficients in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{m-2}]$